# GroupBy multiple properties in nested objects dynamically

Tags: c#, reflection, lambda, expression

### Problem

I have a list of objects that needs to be grouped by multiple properties during run-time.

```
public class ParentClass {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public NestedClassOne NestedOne { get; set; }
    public NestedClassThree NestedThree { get; set; }
}

public class NestedClassOne {
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public NestedClassTwo NestedTwo { get; set; }
}

public class NestedClassTwo {
    public string Data { get; set; }
}

public class NestedClassThree {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

var data = new List<ParentClass> {
    new ParentClass {
        ID = 1,
        Name = "Car";
        NestedOne = new NestedClassOne {
            Make = "Toyota";
            Model = "Corolla";
            NestedTwo = new NestedClassTwo {
                Data = "Auto"
            };
        };
        NestedThree = new NestedClassThree {
            Name = "Smith";
        };
    },
    new ParentClass {
        ID = 2,
        Name = "Car";
        NestedOne = new NestedClassOne {
            Make = "Nissan";
            Model = "GTR";
            NestedTwo = new NestedClassTwo {
                Data = "Manual"
            };
        };
        NestedThree = new NestedClassThree {
            Name = "Taylor";
        };
    },
    new ParentClass {
        ID = 3,
        Name = "Car";
        NestedOne = new NestedClassOne {
            Make = "Toyota";
            Model = "Corolla";
            NestedTwo = new NestedClassTwo {
                Data = "Manual"
            };
        };
        NestedThree = new NestedClassThree {
            Name = "Jack";
        };
    },
    new ParentClass {
        ID = 4,
        Name = "Jeep";
        NestedOne = new NestedClassOne {
            Make = "Nissan";
            Model = "X-Trail";
            NestedTwo = new NestedClassTwo {
                Data = "Auto"
            };
        };
        NestedThree = new NestedClassThree {
            Name = "Jack";
        };
    },
    new ParentClass {
        ID = 5,
        Name = "Jeep";
        NestedOne = new NestedClassOne {
            Make = "Toyota";
            Model = "Vantage";
            NestedTwo = new NestedClassTwo {
                Data = "Manual"
            };
        };
        NestedThree = new NestedClassThree {
            Name = "Shawna";
        };
    }
};
```

I get a list of property names like `"Name", "NestedOne.NestedTwo.Data", "NestedOne.Make"`. So using this list of property names, the code needs to group the above list of data, so that functions such as 'Count' can be executed on them.

### Approach

I've tried to use Reflection to obtain the property values and create a new `ExpandoObject` which would then be passed into 'GroupBy' method. However, it seems that ExpandoObjects are not supported.

Therefore, researching into it, I ran into an amazing solution here on this link.

[GroupBy(params string[] fields) | Code Review StackExchanage](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/173128/groupbyparams-string-fields/)

This pretty much, solves my problem as long as the properties are on the parent object itself. It doesn't support generating the Expressions, for the nested properties such as `"NestedOne.NestedTwo.Data", "NestedOne.Make"`.

Desired output would be similar to this.

```
Name    |  NestedOne.Make    |  NestedOne.NestedTwo.Data    |  Count
========|====================|==============================|=========
Car     |  Toyota            |  Manual                      |  27  
Car     |  Nissan            |  Manual                      |  09  
Jeep    |  Toyota            |  Auto                        |  15  
Jeep    |  Nissan            |  Auto                        |  36
```

### Request

I am quite familiar with C-Sharp. However, I am a novice when it comes to 'Expression' building. Is my approach to this problem correct? Is there an easier way to achieve this functionality? Can anyone help me out? I would appreciate any help at this point, regardless how small it is.

Thank you everyone